# possible to add a row number to a SELECT clause that is not order dependent

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

If I have this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5c1e3/1)

```
CREATE TABLE temp
(
y          char(9),
x          char(9)
);

insert into temp (x, y) values ('j', 'hello');
insert into temp (x, y) values ('j', 'world');
insert into temp (x, y) values ('q', 'foo');
insert into temp (x, y) values ('q', 'bar');

select 
x
,y
from temp
```

I'd like to have a row number included in the SELECT clause. So the result would look like this:

```
x y     r
j hello 1 
j world 2
q foo   3
q bar   4
```

I don't believe Row_number() over will work as this requires an Order and I do not want to change the order from the `SELECT * FROM`. Also do not want to an an identity column to the client db table

Is this possible in SQL-Server?

Comment: Are you okay with the `r` value not necessarily matching up to the same row every time you run the query? Why do you not care about order? Does it really not matter what order these results are returned to the client? Why not just have the client apply a row number, since it has to loop through them to display anyway, and most client languages are quite capable of maintaining a counter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're okay with `r` being non-deterministic (in other words it may not work the same every time):

```
select 
x
,y
, r = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
from temp
order by r;
```

To see even a very simple case where it doesn't work the same way:

```
CREATE TABLE temp
(
y          char(9) PRIMARY KEY,
x          char(9)
);
```

And of course if you want the order to be random:

```
select 
x
,y
, r = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NEWID())
from temp
order by r;
```

Comment: Doesn't SQL Server allow `row_number() over ()` (as defined by the SQL standard)?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name no, `Msg 4112, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
The function 'ROW_NUMBER' must have an OVER clause with ORDER BY.` This is still a gap in functionality in SQL Server 2012 (even though they made numerous other enhancements to windowing functionality).

Comment: like the use of NULL in your first script + I've not come across NEWID() before - thanks

Comment: @AaronBertrand: thanks for the feedback. I wasn't aware that SQL Server's windowing function are still limited.